# Tkinter Combobox textvariable not displaying default or changing upon selection

Tags: tkinter

```
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.begSplit = StringVar(value = '# of Days')
        self.begDur = StringVar(value = '# of Weeks')
        self.begsSplits = ['4 Days, Upper/Lower x2', '3 Days, Full Body']
        self.begsDurs = ['4 Weeks', '8 Weeks']
        self.begPanel()


def begPanel(self):
        self.freq = Tk()
        self.freq.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(self.window_width, self.window_height, self.xCoord, self.yCoord))
        self.freq.title("BEGINNER: Training Splits & Frequency")
        
        begDur_cb = Combobox(self.freq, textvariable = self.begDur, font = ("Arial", 11), values = self.begsDurs)
        begDur_cb.place(relheight = 0.1 , relwidth = 0.4, relx = 0.3, rely = 0.3)
        
        begDurVar = StringVar()
        begDurlabel = Label(self.freq, textvariable = begDurVar, font = ("Arial", 11))
        begDurVar.set("Duration in Weeks:")
        begDurlabel.place(relheight = 0.1 , relwidth = 0.2025, relx = 0.09, rely = 0.305)
```

For some reason the textvariable *self.begDur* fails to change to the value selected by the combobox, it just remains as the default value. Maybe someone can see why.

Comment: Does the class of these functions inherit from `Tk`?

Comment: Nope, should it?

Comment: Then there should be another instance of `Tk()` elsewhere because the issue is most probably due to more than one instance of `Tk()`. Try changing `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `begPanel()`.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason the textvariable self.begDur fails to change to the
> value selected by the combobox.

Don't use `from tkinter import *`

Add namespace `from tkinter import ttk`

I commented out on `geometry`. I don't know what those parameter are.

Add `root.withdraw()` before `mainloop()`  to prevent blank window.

Change this `self.freq = Tk()` to `self.freq = tk.Toplevel()` in `begPanel` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()

class App:

    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.begSplit = tk.StringVar(value = '# of Days')
            self.begDur = tk.StringVar(value = '# of Weeks')
            self.begsSplits = ['4 Days, Upper/Lower x2', '3 Days, Full Body']
            self.begsDurs = ['4 Weeks', '8 Weeks']
            self.begPanel()


    def begPanel(self):
            self.freq = tk.Toplevel()
            #self.freq.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(self.window_width, self.window_height, self.xCoord, self.yCoord))
            self.freq.title("BEGINNER: Training Splits & Frequency")
            
            begDur_cb = ttk.Combobox(self.freq, textvariable = self.begDur, font = ("Arial", 11), values = self.begsDurs)
            begDur_cb.place(relheight = 0.1 , relwidth = 0.4, relx = 0.3, rely = 0.3)
            
            begDurVar = tk.StringVar()
            begDurlabel = tk.Label(self.freq, textvariable = begDurVar, font = ("Arial", 11))
            begDurVar.set("Duration in Weeks:")
            begDurlabel.place(relheight = 0.1 , relwidth = 0.2025, relx = 0.09, rely = 0.305)

app = App()
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]